# Is this a linux or a virtualenv error?

Tags: python, django, linux, virtualenv, python-2.7

I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/mint-12-synaptic-package-manager-error) 4 days ago.

Now, when I open a terminal, I see this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Is it related to the initial problem i had, or it a python and virtualenv issue?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: @paxdiablo not a programming question, but a python error question :P I should fix this error before i can start programming and start asking question about programming :)

Comment: if you want me to delete it, tell me

Comment: You should ask a real question: **explain your problem** and paste here a complete traceback, if you have one. Do not link us to your desktop screen shots. If you really think it could help add a note at the end with a link to that other related question, but that link cannot be a question here. If you don't take some the time for asking a good question, no one will ever give you a good answer.

Comment: Apologies to OP. I saw the errors for gnome-panel in the first graphic and thought that's what the problem was. The second graphic I could barely read :-) I've cleaned up the images and included them in the question rather than as separate links.

Comment: @RikPoggi you are right sir, sorry

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks sir, I apologies for being in a hurry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using `su` and `sudo` to run virtualenv. You need to run virtualenv as your normal user. You have created the virtualenv with `sudo` which is why you are getting these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to just give the write permission for you on the virtualenv private dir?

```
chmod +w -R ~/.virtualenv
```

That should resolve the Permission Denied issue.