# How to install virtualenv without using sudo?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip, easy-install

I have `easy_install` and `pip`.

I had many errors on my **Linux Mint 12**, I just re-installed it and I want to install everything from scratch again.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340637/is-this-a-linux-or-a-virtualenv-error/9341580#9341580) is one of the errors that I had. I received an interesting answer there:

> Stop using su and sudo to run virtualenv.
>   You need to run virtualenv as your normal user.
>   You have created the virtualenv with sudo which is why you are getting these errors.

So how to install `virtualenv` without using `sudo`? Can i use `pip`or `easy_install` without using `sudo`? Or is there another way?

Comment: Note that when it says `su` and `sudo`, what it actually means is `as root`. You're running `virtualenv` as root, and `virtualenv` doesn't want to be run as root. Drop privileges and try again.

Comment: There is a big difference between installing `virtualenv` as root, verses *running* it as root. The quote you inserted is not talking about installing `virtualenv`, but using it to set up a virtual environment for a Python project.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This solution is suitable in cases where no `virtualenv` is available system wide and you can not become root to install `virtualenv`. When I set up a debian for python development or deployment I always `apt-get install python-virtualenv`. It is more convenient to have it around than to do the bootstrap pointed out below. But without root power it may be the the way to go:

There is a bootstrap mechanism that should get you going.

Read: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#creating-a-virtual-python

In essence you would do this in your home directory in a unix environment:

Given your python is version 2.6

```
    $ mkdir ~/bin
    $ mkdir -p ~/lib/python2.6
    $ mkdir -p ~/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
    $ wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/virtual-python.py
    $ python virtual-python.py --no-site-packages
    $ wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
    $ ~/bin/python ez_setup.py
    $ ~/local/bin/easy_install virtualenv
    $ ~/local/bin/virtualenv --no-site-packages thereyouare
```

There may be room for optimization. I don't like the `local` path. Just `bin` and `lib` would be nice. But it does its job.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your solution!
Using `python virtual-python.py --no-site-packages --prefix=\`pwd\``, we can install `virtual-python` into folder other than the home folder, to prevent directory pollution.

Comment: with the -p switch you only need the third line...  recursive directory creation just happens.

Comment: Perhaps this was valid for older versions of virtualenv. For now, if you want to run virtualenv on a machine you're not root: download and untar one if these: `https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/releases`, then then just run `python virtualenv.py /path/to/new/virtualenv/to/create`

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the command below, it worked for me without `sudo` access.
You may also need to modify your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable using `export`, [see this SO answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465445/how-to-install-python-modules-without-root-access).

`pip install --user virtualenv`

Answer (score 14):

The general idea is to install `virtualenv` itself globaly, i.e. `sudo easy_install virtualenv` or `sudo pip install virtualenv`, but then *create* the actual virtual environment ("run virtualenv") locally.

Comment: // , The question is, though, how. Many of the virtualenv packages, especially for CEntOS 6, end up requiring sudo once installed.

Answer (score 10):

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/ suggests the following:

```
curl -L -o virtualenv.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
python virtualenv.py vvv-venv
. vvv-venv/bin/activate
pip install vvv
```

It seems to work well. It lets me install https://github.com/miohtama/vvv with `pip`.

If you get:

```
Cannot find sdist setuptools-*.tar.gz
Cannot find sdist pip-*.tar.gz
```

Try `--extra-search-dir` after downloading the tarballs at https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tree/develop/virtualenv_support

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19404371/1888983) worked for me:

```
pip install --target=$HOME/virtualenv/ virtualenv
cd somewhere/
python $HOME/virtualenv/virtualenv.py env
. env/bin/activate
```

Now I can `pip install` whatever I want (except for everything that needs to compile stuff with gcc and has missing dependencies such as the python development libraries and `Python.h`).

Answer (score 4):

Basically the idea is to install virtualenv (or any other python package) into `${HOME}/.local`. This is the most appropriate location since it is included into python path by default (and not only Python).

That you do by `pip3 install virtualenv --prefix=${HOME}/.local` (you may need to expand `${HOME}`).
Make sure that you have `export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}` in your `~/.profile` (you may need to `source ~/.profile` it if just added)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a "portable" [version of virtualenv](https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/locally/src/tip/06.get-virtualenv.py).

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/techtonik/locally/raw/tip/06.get-virtualenv.py
python 06.get-virtualenv.py
```

It downloads `virtualenv.py` script with dependencies into `.locally` subdir and executes it from there. Once that's done, the script with .locally/ subdir can be copied anywhere.

Comment: Using your solution I get this error:   
`Checking hash/size for /files/spegni/.locally/virtualenv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "06.get-virtualenv.py", line 163, in <module>
getsecure(LOOT, filespec)
  File "06.get-virtualenv.py", line 132, in getsecure
check(filepath, entry['hashsize'], quiet)
  File "06.get-virtualenv.py", line 113, in check
 % (filepath, shize, hashsize(filepath)))
__main__.HashSizeCheckFailed: Hash/Size mismatch for /files/spegni/.locally/virtualenv.py
  exp: a506a836ef76301bc19e5a209984a4286529a79b 98477
  act: d205cbd6783332a212c5ae92d73c77178c2d2f28 9`

Comment: @FSp, pypa team killed the branch for 1.11.x version. Fixed. Try now.

Comment: Updated to virtualenv 12.0.7

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem installing virtualenv for each user.

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It's a full-fledged Python distribution, that lives in a folder in e.g. your home directory. No `sudo` is necessary at any point and you get most of the popular packages.

```
$ wget https://.../Anaconda2-2.5.0-Linux-x86_64.sh # check the website for the exact URL, it can change
$ bash Anaconda2-2.5.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ conda install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I have seen so far is to install Anaconda.
It may be an overkill for you. For me the centOS running on the remote server had only python2.6 installed. Anaconda by default installs everything locally + it is python2.7

```
curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Then

```
bash Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Boom. You have all the packages like numpy and pip installed.
Then if you want virtualenv, just type

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: This doesn't answers OP's question. He already has pip and wants to install virtualenv without doing sudo.

Comment: @Ghazi The question says: "I want to install everything from scratch again". Again even if it doesn't answer the OP's question precisely, someone else will find it useful as I.

Comment: And what is "everything" defined as? Anaconda is everything according to you?

Comment: It is open to interpretation unless the OP clarifies it. I understood it as similar to my situation where he had access to a remote server, so he doesn't have access to root privileges. So he wants to install virtualenv. I think installing anaconda is the easiest way to solve this problem. He needs no sudo privilege for doing that. Moreover he has all the python packages pre-bundled.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough. Your answer just popped up in the review queue for quality check.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo virtualenv -p python myenv1

sudo su
source myenv1/bin/activate


pip install mypackage
```

this is will install inside virtual environment

Comment: he said no sudo

Answer (score 0):

The lack of sudo is a common situation in many shared remote server.

It turns out, there is a simpler, lightweight, more secure solution. Just download an official "portable" virtualenv from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/virtualenv.pyz

And that is it! You can now run `python virtualenv.pyz --help` to your heart's content.

Official document: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#via-zipapp