# buildout and setuptools requirement

Tags: django, setuptools

when I call 
python ./bootstrap.py on mutual server I have this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bootstrap.py", line 74, in 
    ws.require('zc.buildout')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 569, in resolve
    plugin_projects = list(plugin_env)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (setuptools 0.6c11 (/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=0.7'))
when I do the same on my computer, it is working fine.

before this I did :

easy_install --install-dir ~/download fez.djangoskel
paster create -t django_buildout xxxxxxxx

does anyone know what could be the problem ?

thanks

Comment: Your cuurent version of setuptools is 0.6c11 and bootstrap.py reqiures setuptools >= 0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said in a comment it seems that your system-wide version of 0.6c11 and bootstrap.py reqiures setuptools >= 0.7. Because messing with global packages is usually bad idea I would recommend using  [virtualenve](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and  [virtualevnwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper/4.1.1)for development and installing all requirements inside virtual environments. On Linux systems both can be easily installed using package managers. 
On Debian (and probably Ubuntu)

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv
apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

After installing all have to do is:

```
mkvirtualenv bar
pip install setuptools>=0.7
```

Then install all other packages that you need and you are ready to go.

**UPDATE**

If you don't have root access virtualenv can be easily installed locally. See this 
[How to install virtualenv without using sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348869/how-to-install-virtualenv-without-using-sudo) for details.

Comment: Hi

thanks for answer. 
Unfortunately as I told, I m on mutual server, so Im not allowed to run apt-get