# Use jinja2 without install

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, python-module, pythonpath

Is it possible to use Jinja2 without installing it using easy_install or pip ? I dont have root access on my server but I would like to use Jinja2. I was wondering if I could do this:

```
import sys,os,cgi,cgitb

this_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(this_dir, "Jinja2-2.7.3.tar.gz"))

from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
```

Edit: Sorry forgot to add but I did try it and I am getting an error : No module named jinja2 , I have confirmed that the path is correct.

2nd Edit: Lukas Graf's solution will probably work but just for information is it possible to do it without virtualenv?

Comment: Use a [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html/) - no root privileges needed.

Comment: yes but to install virtualenv i need sudo

Comment: See [How to install virtualenv without using sudo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348869/how-to-install-virtualenv-without-using-sudo)

Comment: is it possible without using virtualenv?

Comment: it is possible. you need to look at the path to see if it's there. if it isn't then it got added to the path for a different version of python. make sure you add it to path for the appropriate version. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/#installation

Comment: okay so from inside my script i printed out sys.path and sure enough I get the correct path of the Jinja folder. Is a problem if the folder is inside cgi-bin (ignoring security)?

Comment: If you *do* want to make it work without installing, you need to make sure you download the `.egg` and not the `tar.gz`. But every time you hack `sys.path`, somewhere a kitten dies. Just use `virtualenv`.