# Is it possible to install aws-cli package without root permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, redhat, aws-cli

As title suggested, I haven't been able to find a good way to install `aws-cli` (https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/) without having the root access (or equivalent of `sudo` privileges).

The way `Homebrew` setup on Mac is hinting at it may be possible, provided that a few directories and permissions are set in a way to facility future installs. However, I have yet to find any approach in Linux (specially, Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS distroes).

I am also aware of SCL from RHEL (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/scl-utils.html) But again, it requires `sudo`.

Comment: Are you trying to use `pip` to install it? Does the `--user` flag not work?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a bundled installer for that purpose.

Install `aws` command to `$HOME/bin`

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ ./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws
```

Set `$PATH` environment variable

```
$ echo $PATH | grep ~/bin     // See if $PATH contains ~/bin (output will be empty if it doesn't)
$ export PATH=~/bin:$PATH     // Add ~/bin to $PATH if necessary
```

Test the AWS CLI Installation

```
$ aws help
```

See the following link for details:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html#install-bundle-user

Comment: Thank you, even without `pip` and other dependencies.

Comment: I believe this only works for AWS CLI v1. See below for recommended v2 solution.

Comment: Yes, this solution installs AWS CLI v1. (tested on 2023-06).

Answer (score 20):

For AWS CLI v2, the recommended solution is passing options `-i` and `-b` when installing indicating directories for which user has write permissions.

Example:

```bash
$ cd Downloads
$ curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
$ unzip awscliv2.zip
$ ./aws/install -i ~/aws-cli -b ~/aws-cli/bin
```

From Amazon Web Service's [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html):

> **You can install without `sudo`** if you specify directories that you already have write permissions to. Use the following instructions for the `install` command to specify the installation location:
>
> - Ensure that the paths you provide to the `-i` and `-b` parameters contain no volume name or directory names that contain any space characters or other white space characters. If there is a space, the installation fails.
> - `--install-dir` or `-i` – This option specifies the directory to copy all of the files to.
>
>   The default value is `/usr/local/aws-cli`.
> - `--bin-dir` or `-b` – This option specifies that the main `aws` program in the install directory is symbolically linked to the file `aws` in the specified path. You must have write permissions to the specified directory. Creating a symlink to a directory that is already in your path eliminates the need to add the install directory to the user's `$PATH` variable.
>
>   The default value is `/usr/local/bin`.

(I believe the accepted answer is outdated in that it only works for AWS CLI v1.)

Comment: I think it would make more sense to put the binary in your user's binary directory instead: `./aws/install -i ~/aws-cli -b ~/bin`

Comment: Actually, better to put it in .local/bin: `./aws/install -i ~/.local/aws-cli -b ~/.local/bin`

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the answers is possible. The trick is to install the whole stack in an alternate location on the host machine.

So altinstall python, then easy_intsall, then pip. Here are the command history in my log.

```
cd
mkdir installations
cd installations/
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tar.bz2
tar xjf Python-2.7.tar.bz2 
cd Python-2.7
mkdir -p ~/usr/local
make altinstall prefix=~/usr/local exec-prefix=~/usr/local
~/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -V
ln -s ~/usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/usr/local/bin/python
echo "export $PATH=~/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
cd
mkdir virtualenv
cd virtualenv/
curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py
mkdir ~/envs
python virtual-python.py --prefix=~/env/aws
curl -O http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
~/env/aws/bin/python ez_setup.py
echo "export $PATH=~/env/aws/bin:~/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
easy_install virtualenv
virtualenv --no-site-packages ~/env/awscli
source ~/env/awscli/bin/activate
pip -V
pip install awscli
```

These are helpful links that I followed to help me achieve that goal.

[Install Python in an alternate location](http://isezen.com/2011/09/02/how-to-install-locally-python-on-linux-home-directory/)

[Install Python stack without root privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349150)

Answer (score 1):

You can install without root access with the `--user` flag to `pip`:

```
pip install --user -U awscli
```

(Hat tip to Etan Reisner who wrote this in a comment).

Comment: This is AWS CLI v1. Do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

After installing aws on my ubuntu 20.04, I faced same issue.
when I tried:

```
aws --version
```

it didn't worked (`Command 'aws' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install awscli`)
and

```
/usr/local/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/2.3.1 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.11.0-38-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
```

Then I can't use aws without sudo privileges

I fixed it by (by adding rights for group and others on /usr/local/aws-cli directory)

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/aws-cli
```

And it works for me!
Let me know if it's ok for you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Quiver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2239016/quiver) works like a charm, except that there is a prerequisite. You need to have **Python** installed too. Given that you don’t have root privileges, you will now end up searching for how to install python without root permission, and that ain’t going to be straightforward either.

So here is the complete solution that finally worked for me.

1. Install Anaconda with wget

```
cd ~
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda3    # Install aws command to $HOME/bin
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

~/anaconda3/bin/conda init  # Reload default profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

2. Use the bundled installer to install aws-cli package

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip
unzip awscli-bundle.zip
./awscli-bundle/install -b ~/bin/aws 
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

3. Test the AWS CLI Installation

```
aws —version
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namei -l /usr/local/bin/aws
```

shows the permissions of each path leading to the actual aws script.

`sudo chmod 777` fixes the permissions for the path that's lacking access from your non-root user.

Answer (score -1):

I use conda to install asw cli:

```
conda install -c conda-forge awscli
```

You don't need root permission to install conda.

Comment: This is AWS CLI v1. Do not use it.