# Add Python entry point to local APPDATA

Tags: python, windows-10, setuptools, python-packaging, windows-11

I am writing a command line tool with Python. It should be as easy as possible for Windows 10 / 11 users to install and use. My goal is to make the following procedure work:

1. Install Python from the Microsoft Store
2. Install my program using `pip install "C:\path\to\myprogram.zip"`
3. Start my program using `myprogram` in Windows cmd

Currently, I have a `setup.py` like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="myprogram",
    # image additional arguments here
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["myprogram=myprogram.module:function"]},
)
```

Everything works great in virtual environments, but I don't want my users to necessarily deal with them. I understand that running the `pip install ...`  command above installs the entry point (in my case) to `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts`, which is obviously not in Windows %PATH%.

So here comes my question: Is it possible to either

1. write the script to one of the Windows %PATH%s (for example `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`) or
2. add `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts` to Windows %PATH%?

I want the solution to work directly from the `setup.py` such that no additional installation step is necessary. I'm fully aware that there is only a small chance to find a solution that is not "hacky" in some way.

---

**Workaround:** As of now, I am building an executable with [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/).

Comment: This sound awfully complicated. Have you looked at PyInstaller or auto-py-to-exe?

Comment: You are absolutely right (this sounds awfully complicated). I have heard of py2exe, I'm just afraid that the security policies then require a Windows admin account? I have to assume that many of my users do not have one. I don't know PyInstaller, can similar problems occur there?

Comment: Just try it. Besides an antivirus scan I have not encountered anything else.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092388/adding-installed-pip-package-to-path-automatically

Comment: @Sebastian: Thought about it during lunch. With these tools I need to implement and maintain some sort of build pipeline. My idea has some sort of charming pinguin style (thinking of `apt install myprog` and `myprog`). The zipfile I mentioned can be downloaded from Github directly.

Comment: @CodeMaster: Very nice approach - unfortunately it only works on Python 2.x and explictly not on Win10 / Win11 (I looked up the paths). The script was removed from cpython couple of month ago...

Comment: @CodeMaster Actually there was a Python 3 script as well - however, it was still removed with the argument being "outdated" ¯\ (ツ) /¯

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look into distributing your program using a [*zipapp*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html)-based solution, maybe [*pex*](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) or [*shiv*](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/). As long as a Python interpreter is installed, it should work without issues.

There are details regarding the handling of *zipapp* on Windows on its [documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html). I recommend making sure that the `.pyz` extension is configured properly to execute on double-click, but you might not be in a position to ensure this. I believe there are also other approaches to handle zipapps/`.pyz` files on Windows, which one you should use all depends on the details of the use case.

---

Another possible solution I would recommend to explore is [*pipx*](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The double-click idea is not possible, since the command line call involves additional parameters.

Comment: @d4tm4x Right, double-click is not necessary since the project is a CLI tool. Anyway, did you try something? pex or shiv?

Comment: I had a look, yes. However, compared to the workaround (see above), I need some build pipelines etc. which is an overhead I try to avoid until my program is hopefully used more and more...

Comment: Your program has no dependencies? It uses only the standard library?

Comment: It uses pandas and plotly to generate visualizations of some kind of "log files" where the paths to such files are passed als command line arguments.

Comment: If the program has dependencies then I recommend it should be either installed in a virtual environment (maybe with pipx) or distributed and used via a zipapp solution (maybe pex or shiv).